# Select multiple target variables in keras tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to follow a kaggle kernel for BERT implementation :
https://www.kaggle.com/hiromoon166/save-bert-fine-tuning-model

But i am not able to select target variables. I have to select multiple target variables as my y variable as it is a multi-label classification.

This is the line of code i am stuck on:

```
train_lines, train_labels = train_df['comment_text'].values, train_df.target.values
```

---

```
def convert_lines(example, max_seq_length,tokenizer):
    max_seq_length -=2
    all_tokens = []
    longer = 0
    for i in range(example.shape[0]):
      tokens_a = tokenizer.tokenize(example[i])
      if len(tokens_a)>max_seq_length:
        tokens_a = tokens_a[:max_seq_length]
        longer += 1
      one_token = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(["[CLS]"]+tokens_a+["[SEP]"])+[0] * (max_seq_length - len(tokens_a))
      all_tokens.append(one_token)
    print(longer)
    return np.array(all_tokens)

nb_epochs=1
bsz = 32
dict_path = os.path.join(BERT_PRETRAINED_DIR, 'vocab.txt')
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=dict_path, do_lower_case=True)
print('build tokenizer done')
train_df = pd.read_csv('../input/jigsaw-unintended-bias-in-toxicity-classification/train.csv')
train_df = train_df.sample(frac=0.01,random_state = 42)
#train_df['comment_text'] = train_df['comment_text'].replace({r'\s+$': '', r'^\s+': ''}, regex=True).replace(r'\n',  ' ', regex=True)

train_lines, train_labels = train_df['comment_text'].values, train_df.target.values 
print('sample used',train_lines.shape)
token_input = convert_lines(train_lines,maxlen,tokenizer)
seg_input = np.zeros((token_input.shape[0],maxlen))
mask_input = np.ones((token_input.shape[0],maxlen))
print(token_input.shape)
print(seg_input.shape)
print(mask_input.shape)
print('begin training')
model3.fit([token_input, seg_input, mask_input],train_labels,batch_size=bsz,epochs=nb_epochs)
```

Please help me understand how to select target variables here?

Comment: If you are too confused, you can decompose the line `train_lines, train_labels = train_df['comment_text'].values, train_df.target.values ` like this:
here `train_lines=train_df['comment_text'].values`, which selects the column named `comment_text` from the dataframe train_df, and converts it to a python `list` of values. Likewise, identify the name of the column for the target and use `train_labels = train_df['column_name_of_target'].values`

Comment: i have to select multiple target variables

Comment: What do you mean by multiple targets here? is it a multi-class classification problem?

Comment: there are 5 different labels as our target variable.

Comment: Are they in same column or different column?

Comment: different columns

Comment: Then you can write a small piece of code to do that.

Comment: i can use df.iloc[,:] , but is this the right way to do it?

Comment: People will be able to better help you if you can post the sample data of trainset, followed by how you want the target to be (If you know), and bit more detailed such as 'multi-class' classification or 'multi-label' classification